# How to check array key is blank

Tags: php

Hello I have an array

```
$data = array('abc'=>'mango', ''=>"banana");
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [vdsdfgdf] => gdfgdfg
    [] => qureshi
)
```

I want to delete blank key and its value.
How to filter keys value

Comment: Just do `unset($data['']);`

Answer (score 0):

Declare Array like so :

`$data = array('abc'=>'mango', ''=>"banana");`

Use validation to check if any empty key exists using the following code:

`if($data['']){
    unset($data['']);
    print_r($data);
}`

This remove the empty key if it exists in the array

Answer (score 0):

First check if the blank key exists or not in your array:

1. array_key_exists()
2. unset that array - Remove blank key from that array (i.e. $data)
   Code:

   if (array_key_exists('',$data))
     {
     unset($data['']);
     }